# How to set pointers throught functions?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question about C pointers. Because I was wondering if I could set pointers through functions.
I mean like this:

```
void initptr(int **ptr)
{
 ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(ptr));
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    initptr(ptr);
}
```

Let me know.

Comment: Yep, but you need to get the types right:  `initptr(&ptr)` `*ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*ptr))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible in C, you're just missing a dereference and address of operator in your sample

```
void initptr(int **ptr)
{
  *ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int*));
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    initptr(&ptr);
}
```

The deference operator in `*ptr = ...` converts the type of `ptr` from `int**` to `int*` thus making it compatible with the assignment.  Note: the casting of malloc is uneedded here.

The address of operator in `initptr(&ptr)` reversely converts the type of `ptr` from `int*` to `int**` thus making it compatible with the argument slot.

**EDIT**

As B Mitch pointed out the malloc size needs updating as well.  You appear to be allocating an `int*` value and hence want the size to be that of an `int*`.

Comment: I believe the sizeof is wrong as well, needing either `**ptr` or `*ptr`, not positive on which.  Though since we are talking about a pointer vs an integer, this may be a non-issue in this specific scenario.

Comment: @ JaredPar
I see. However I the result must be:
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))
Is this stil the end result?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this:

```
*ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(**ptr));
```

Comment: And yes, JaredPar caught another error, `initptr` needs `&ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(ptr));
```

You missed to dereference the pointer to pointer so that it can actually take a pointer.

```
*ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(ptr));
// * newly added.
```

And also call to `initptr(ptr);` is wrong.

```
void initptr(int **ptr) ;
```

The function has an pointer to pointer as an argument. So, the argument `ptr` needs to hold the address of a pointer. So, change it to -

```
 int *ptr = NULL ;  // Initialize pointers to NULL
 initptr(&ptr);     // Passing the pointers address
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you need dereference ptr in your function in order to change what it points to

e.g.

```
void initptr(int **ptr)
{
  *ptr = ...
}
```

when you call the method write

```
initptr( &ptr );
```